# useEffect() isn't getting called when the component is re-rendered. It only gets called once after a change in the file is made

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

the useEffect() part of the react component only gets called the first time the `SingleStock` component is rendered after I make a change in the file and save the file. I have no clue why this is happening.

```
import useAuthContext from "../hooks/useAuthContext" 
import StockDetails from "./StockDetails"
import TableHeader from "./TableHeader"
import useStocksContext from '../hooks/useStocksContext'
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const SingleStock = () => {

    console.log('SS RENDERED')

    const {user} = useAuthContext()
    const {stocks, dispatch} = useStocksContext()
    const [stock, setStock] = useState({})

    const id = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]

    useEffect(() => {

        if (!user) {
            return
        }

        const fetchStock = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(`/api/stocks/${id}`, {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.token}`
                }
            })
            let json = await response.json()
            setStock(json)
        }

        console.log('hey there')

        if (user) {
            fetchStock()
        }
    }, [])

    console.log(stock)
    
    return (
        <div>
            <TableHeader/>
            {stock && <StockDetails 
                key={stock._id}
                stock={stock}
            />}
        </div>
    )
}

export default SingleStock
```

I know `SingleStock` is getting re-rendered because of my console.log statement at the top of the file. I know useEffect() isn't running because the state `stock` isn't getting set and "hey there" isn't getting logged to the console. I am stuck.

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya No, the user isn't null and it isn't getting returned there because the `TableHeader` and `StockDetails` components are rendering

Comment: Yah because you explicitly tells React to do so by using empty array as a dependencies of the effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There three cases for `useEffect`

1- if you want it to be executed in each render you should not specify the array of prop, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  //Runs on every render
});
```

2- if you want it to be executed just at the first render, same as `componentDidMount`, use it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  //Runs only on the first render
}, []);
```

3- if you want it to be executed depending on the change of a value or multiple values, use it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  //Runs on the first render
  //And any time any dependency value changes
}, [value1, value2]);
```

in your case I guess you need to use the first approach

Comment: Well... This would make unnecessary calls to fetch a stock with the same ID on every render. I suggest creating a state to keep in memory for the component with id for the stock. Than add it as a dependency in the array. Whenever the id changes, fetch stock is hit. Looks like we are making requests to the db fetching the same stock is on every render. Worth having a look at server calls if that ain't the case.

Comment: @FelipedeAbreuPrazeres yes you're totally right I just gave a suggestion depending on exactly what he asked for, but to improve his code he should use the third approach as you suggest.